# Вызов методов класса через указатель на функцию

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы, указатели

Хочу реализовать возможность передавать в качестве аргумента функции указатель на метод разных классов.

```
class A1
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "A1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B1
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "B1" << std::endl;
    }
};

void callf(void (*fp)())
{
    fp();
}

int main()
{
    callf(&A1::show);
    callf(&B1::show);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Указатель на нестатический метод класса" не является "указателем на функцию". Эти две категории типов фундаментально различны и между собой не совместимы. У вас в программе присутсвует некая попытка вызвать метод класса не создавая ни одного объекта класса. Это, очевидно - полная бессмыслица. Объясните детальнее, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @AnT они различны, но не  слишком — оба представимы как std::function. А в некоторых языках это вообще буквально один и тот же тип—фундаментально для программиста это проявления концепции вызываемого объекта. Намерение `callf()` это частный случай `std::invoke()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В вашем варианте забыта мелочь - то, что нестатическая функция-член требует наличия объекта, для которого вызывается. Так что просто так вызвать не получится, нужен объект.

Или статическая функция.

Вот так - запросто:

```
class A1
{
public:
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "A1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B1
{
public:
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "B1" << std::endl;
    }
};

void callf(void (*fp)())
{
    fp();
}

int main()
{
    callf(&A1::show);
    callf(&B1::show);

    return 0;
}
```

Если все же не статические - то, например, вот:

```
class A1
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "A1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B1
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "B1" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
void callf(T& t, void (T::*f)())
{
    (t.*f)();
}

int main()
{
    A1 a;
    B1 b;
    callf(a,&A1::show);
    callf(b,&B1::show);

    return 0;
}
```