# безопасно вызвать нестатический метод без создания экземпляра типа

Tags: c++, c++11, методы

рассмотрим такой код для стандарта с++03:

```
struct A
{
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "~A()" << endl; }

    void foo() { cout << "foo()" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A* pa = (A*)0;

    pa->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

который компилируется и вполне успешно отрабатывает

возникли следующие вопросы:

1) Почему для виртуальной версии метода `foo` программа падает ?

2) Как безопасно вызвать нестатический метод `foo` средствами с++11 так, чтобы методу `foo` валидно передавался `this`, дабы избежать `UB` при его использовании  ?

Comment: По большому счету, вы хотите того же, что и в этом вопросе - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632155/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e - вызвать функцию-член без объекта...

Comment: @Harry несовсем, так там через создание объектов происходит вызов, но я уже разобрался...а вот минус не пойму кто всё время ставит мне

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ваш код содержит undefined behaviour, как вы понимаете. Вызов метода по нулевому указателю недопустим.

   Если компилятор компилирует вызов невиртуальных методов в статически определённый вызов метода с передачей `this` как скрытого параметра, и вы в коде метода не разыменовываете `this`, и оптимизатор решил не пользоваться явным UB, это *может* не упасть.

   Точно так же *может* не упасть и вызов виртуального метода, если оптимизатор проведёт flow analysis вашего кода, обнаружит, что знает на деле точный тип аргумента, проведёт *девиртуализацию* и вызовет метод статическим образом. А может и упасть, если оптимизатор решит вызывать через таблицу виртуальных методов.

   UB, оно такое, может повезти, а может и не повезти.
2. По стандарту — никак. Нестатический метод можно вызывать лишь имея на руках объект (или указатель на объект), тип которого совпадает с нужным или производный от него. Вы не можете «передать свой `this`» явным образом. А раз есть объект, то он был сконструирован.

   А вызов по указателю на другой объект или по нулевому указателю — UB. Не делайте так.

---

С другой стороны, если вы пишете код под конкретный компилятор, его иногда *можно* попросить проглотить вызов через `nullptr` и вызвать instance-метод без наличия `this`. Но это серая зона вне действия стандарта. Не стоит делать так без реальной *крайней* на то необходимости.

Comment: Все не так однозначно. Тема того, что можно, а что нельзя делать с нулевым указателем, до сих пор находится в недоспецифицированном состоянии в стандарте С++. Обратите внимание на DR#315 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#315) который пытается открытым текстом утверждать, что вызов нестатического метода через нулевой указатель является законным (!). А вообще это частный случай большой темы DR#232 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232) и компании, которая с незапамятных времен болтается в подвешенном состоянии.

Comment: @AnT: Но вроде бы законность вызова функций-членов по `nullptr` не принята ещё? Я правильно понимаю, что это осталось лишь в форме предложений тех самых ассемблерщиков-на-C++?

Comment: вообще-то operator-> и operator. в купе с оператором вызова как раз и есть передача this явным образом. Именно поэтому вызов функции по указателю на член другого класса, являющемуся полем класса observer может выглядеть как что-то вроде calledObject->(observer.func_ptr)().  для более явной реализации есть std::bind

Comment: @Swift: Передача может быть только в контексте параметров. То, что вызов `this->method()` «как бы передаёт» `this` в `method()`, не означает, что оно передаётся на самом деле. Иначе можно и общение кусков кода через глобальный параметр назвать «передачей». Если отвлечься от тонкостей семантики, то «передать» таким образом что угодно (тот же `nullptr`) вы не сможете: раз это UB, оптимизатор имеет полное право считать этот код недостижимым и выкинуть его, например. (И да, реальные оптимизаторы реально пользуются UB для оптимизации.)

Comment: @Swift Это я знаю. Отчасти UB существуют чтобы не  создавать неразрешимых проблем при попытке соответствовать стандарту на некоторых платформах. Я имел в виду абстрактную передачу при задействовании метода класса.  Из-за этого и существует проблема с союзами или преобразованием указателей к разным типам - код может вообще не воспользоваться тем же участком памяти а временным значением в регистре и .т.д. И обращение  к глобальной переменной на самом деле может оказаться передачей через регистр, gcc так делает в некоторых случаях

Answer (score 5):

1) Это неопределённое поведение. Почему то, что Вы написали, работает - ответ надо искать в реализации компилятора и созданного им кода. Подсказка - в одном случае присутствует неявно подставляемая inline функция, описанная в теле класса. В другом - есть необходимость наличия инициализированной виртуальной таблицы когда функция виртуальна, ведь адрес функции хранится в ней. Стандарт не  описывает реализацию и рассматривает платформу как абстрактную машину фон Неймана.

Будь результатом корректная работа, утечка памяти, полное стирание вашего жёсткого диска, расплавленный процессор или вылетающие из вашего носа демоны, начинающие над вами издеваться - это не важно, так как НЕ определено стандартом. Оно может вести себя так в одном компиляторе и по-другому в другом, может меняться в зависимости от версии компилятора, может меняться при каждой компиляции,  при смене фазы луны, в присутствии начальства и в зависимости от вашего настроения и количества нейтрино, пролетевших сквозь процессор в прошлый солнечный день. А может и не меняться.

2) В принципе есть легальный способ вызова, если *уже существует* экземпляр класса.  Указатель на него все-таки придется передать. Сделать это можно с помощью std::bind. Эта функция  вернет вызываемый объект, который будет хранить привязку метода к экземпляру объекта. Если ни одного объекта нет - то никак, если не нарушать стандарт.

Единственное для чего можно использовать нулевой указатель - это для определения смещения поля, но данный прием стандартизирован в виде offsetof (определен в `<cstddef>`), запись которого может зависеть от компилятора, опять таки.

Возможно Ваша проблема - вызов нестатического метода из статического. когда указатель this известен (например, может быть передан статическому члену)? Вот пример, который обсуждался на англоязычном сайте:

```
class Test
{
 typedef void (Test::*ptrToMemberFunc)();
 ptrToMemberFunc function;
public:
    Test(int pointTo)
    {
        if (pointTo == 1)
            function = &Test::Function1;
        else
            function = &Test::Function2;
    }

    static void CallIt(void* cStyle)
    {
        Test* t(static_cast<Test*>(cStyle));

        Test::ptrToMemberFunc pf(t->function);

        // Внутренний -> - доступ к полю. Внешний -> передает t как this
        (t->*(t->function))();
    }

    void CallIt()
    {
        (this->*function)(); // -> передает this указателю на член

    }

private:
    void Function1()
    {
        std::cout << "Function 1" << std::endl;
    }

    void Function2()
    {
        std::cout << "Function 2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

В данном случае  используется нестатический указатель, инициализируемый в конструкторе, поэтому и появляется странная конструкция (t->*(t->function))(); Этот пример имитирует работу виртуальной таблицы без создания класса-потомка, и из этого кода очевидно, где происходит падение, когда вы описываете функцию виртуальной.

Answer (score 2):

Позвольте сформулировать так - если метод может быть вызван **без создания экземпляра класса**, то он по определению статический.
Не преумножайте сущности сверх необходимости, как говорил Оккам, и делайте такой метод статическим.
Иначе ваш проект аналогичен вопросу - как бы заставить туловище двигаться без головы. Говорят, такие случаи бывают... но очень ненадежно и ненадолго.

Comment: конечно можно сделать статическим метод и вызывать его спокойно без костылей, поверьте уж, я об этом в курсе...но вопрос совсем не про это...

Answer (score 0):

Из обходных путей в голову пришел только crtp;
Пример кода выглядит как-то так:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};

    void foo() { static_cast<T*>(this)->foo(); }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    B(){};
    ~B(){};

    void foo() { std::cout << "my leg... my fucking leg... " << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    A<B>* a = nullptr;
    a->foo();

    std::cout << "seems ok" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Насчет безопасности надеюсь понятно, т.к. разыменование нулового указателя как бы УБ чистой воды:)

P.S. этот кусок моё имхо, я его в дизасме не проверял. 
С точки зрения компилятора фиолетово статическая функция или нестатическая, вызов нестатической функции скорее всего выглядит как-то так: `A::foo(&a);` Соответственно передать туда можно любое &a, все будет работать до тех пор, пока не понадобится this, вот тут и будет УБ. Т.е. если нестатическая функция-член foo() реализует статическое поведение (можно без проблем дописать перед ней `static`), то конструкции вида `((A*)nullptr)->foo();` вполне жизнеспособна, хотя и является де-юре UB.

Comment: Ну, эээ, `a->foo();` ведь точно такое же UB?

Comment: конечно же УБ. И с точки зрения стандарта такого способа нет.