# Универсальный вызов методов различных классов через указатель на функцию?

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Есть метод ReadData, который должен работать с тремя типами файлов: txt, accdb, xlsx.

Проблема заключается в том, что передаваемые в него файлы, имеют очень большой объем  - точно более милионна записей.
Поэтому,  приходится читать отдельными блоками.

Вся "логика" проверки размера блоков и.т.д, которая содержится в этом методе - по-сути одинакова для всех трех типов файлов. Разница сотстоит только в том, что в случае текстового файла чтение выполняется с помощью метода readLine, для эксель-файла - метод readRow (я использую библиотеку QXlsx), для accdb - результат sql запроса.
Причем, чтение выполняется (что логично) в цикле и вынести как-то логику проверок в отдельный метод, пока что мне - не представляется возможным.

**Чего я хочу добиться:**

Я хочу, что бы в метод можно было, с помощью шаблонов и кортежей передавать - передавать нужный объект и указатель на метод этого объекта, который необходимо вызывать.
Вот, как сейчас выглядит сигнатура этого метода:

```
template<class T, class D,class... K>
    static QStringList* readData(T& t, D (T::*f)(K... ));
```

-вариант с таким вызовом взял из этого ответа:

**https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632158/203448**

> ```
> template<class T>
> void callf(T& t, void (T::*f)())
> {
>     (t.*f)();
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     A1 a;
>     B1 b;
>     callf(a,&A1::show);
>     callf(b,&B1::show);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Предполагается, что метод будет вызывать следующие методы внутри себя (т.е в качестве
`D (T::*f)(K... )` - будут передаваться:)

- `QByteArray readLine(qint64 maxlen = 0);`
- `QVariant Document::read(int row, int col) const`

(или его перегрузка `QVariant Document::read(const CellReference &cell) const`)

- Для accdb файл еще не продумал

Т.е, для текстового файла это будет:

```
readData<QFile,QByteArray,long long>(*currentOpenTxt,&QFile::readLine)
```

- и этот вариант замечательно работает на практике - вот его вызов:

```
 while (!currentOpenTxt->atEnd()) {
                tmpReadContainer.append((t.*f)(0));
            }
```

(пока что, для упрощения, я оставил здесь `!currentOpenTxt->atEnd()`, но позже, тооже буду думать над метом-оберткой.)
Проблема возникает, когда я пытаюсь сделать тоже самое для метода `QVariant Document::read(int row, int col) const`  - вот так:

```
readData<QXlsx::Document,QVariant,const QXlsx::CellReference&>
                        (*xlsxR,&QXlsx::Document::read)
```

И получаю следующую ошибку:

> no matching function for call to
> 'FileOpenClass::readData<QXlsx::Document, QVariant,
> QXlsx::CellReference>(QXlsx::Document&, )'
> insertData( readDataQXlsx::Document,QVariant,QXlsx::CellReference(*xlsxR,&QXlsx::Document::read));

- т.е, категорически не хочет воспринимать QVariant как тип для шаблона.

Вторая проблема состоит в том, что в качестве параметров метода, я использую кортеж

```
   D (T::*f)(K... k)
```

, но при вызове метода:   `tmpReadContainer.append((t.*f)(k...));` - не могу обратиться к нему подобным образом

(поэтому, оставил пока что в коде:  `tmpReadContainer.append((t.*f)(0));` - т.к тестировал только для readLine метода)

Вот полный код метода `readData`:

```
QStringList* FileOpenClass::readData(T& t, D (T::*f)(K... k))
{
    tmpReadContainer.clear();
    txtFileRowsCount=countTxtLines();
    if (txtFileRowsCount<maxRowsCount) {
        //currentOpenTxt->seek(0);
        while (!currentOpenTxt->atEnd()) {
            tmpReadContainer.append((t.*f)(0)); // чтение разных файлов здесь
        }
    }
    else {
        static bool firstRead=true;
        static int blockCount=1;
        static  int blockSize=0;
        static int alreadyReadBlock=0;
        static bool tailWrote=false;
        while(!tailWrote)
        {
            if (allReadFlag) {
                //tail
                blockSize=txtFileRowsCount-alreadyReadBlock*blockSize;
                for (int var = 0; var < blockSize; ++var) {
                    tmpReadContainer.append((t.*f)(0));//здесь
                }
                tailWrote=true;
            }
            else
            {
                while(!allReadFlag)
                {
                    if (firstRead) {
                        currentOpenTxt->seek(0);
                        while (txtFileRowsCount%blockCount==0) {
                            blockCount++;
                        }
                        blockSize =txtFileRowsCount/blockCount;
                        firstRead=false;
                        qDebug()<<blockSize<<endl;
                    }
                    //first read end
                    else
                    {
                        //read block
                        for (int var = 0; var < blockSize; ++var) {
                            tmpReadContainer.append((t.*f)(0)); // и здесь
                        }
                        alreadyReadBlock++;
                        if (alreadyReadBlock==blockCount) {
                            allReadFlag=true;
                        }
                        if (txtFileRowsCount%blockSize==0) {
                            tailWrote=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //qDebug()<<tmpReadContainer.size();
    return &tmpReadContainer;
}
```

**Ряд вопросов:**

1. Как можно обойти проблему с QVariant в качесиве типа для шаблона?
2. Как правильно обратиться к кортежу в данном случае?

**Более общие вопросы:**

3. Как лучше переписать/изменить код в подобной ситуации - тюе когда имеется почти одиаковый код и не хочется иметь три практически идентиных метода?
4. Посоветуйте, что почитать/посмотреть про написание "универсального и гибкого" кода (обращаю вгимание, что в " " - т.к понимаю, что не существует "серебряной пули", этот вопрос скорее про техники/методологмм/подходы - ведь должны же такие существовать?)

Comment: *Как лучше переписать/изменить код в подобной ситуации - тюе когда имеется почти одиаковый код и не хочется иметь три практически идентиных метода?* - вынесите `tmpReadContainer.append((t.*f)(0));` в отдельную функцию и в ней используйте `constexpr if` в зависимости от типа параметра

Comment: *Посоветуйте, что почитать/посмотреть про написание "универсального и гибкого" кода* - много чего, если конкретно про универсальную передачу параметров в функции - ищите в доках/стандарте forwarding reference и parameter packs

Comment: [Зачем нужен std::invoke?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848131/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-stdinvoke/848165#848165)

Comment: @user7860670, не могли бы вы добавить пример для std::invoke ? Просто смотрю на Ваш ответ и не совсем могу понять, как мне это сделать у себя в коде? + я так и не разобрался , как в таком случае, использовать кортеж для переменного числа параметров?

Comment: вот у вас написано "я использую кортеж D (T::*f)(K... k)" - это не кортеж, а указатель на функцию, в которую надо передать пачку параметров `k...` которые надо где-то раздобыть `::std::invoke(f, Tinstance, args...)`

Comment: @user7860670, не могли бы Вы еще кое-что подсказать? я не могу понять, как вызвать мой шаблонный метод?  - т.е, что подставить вместо "?"
`readData<?,?,?>(&QFile::readLine,&currentOpenTxt,0)`
Пробовал `readData<QFile,QFile,int>(&QFile::readLine,&currentOpenTxt,0)` - пишет, что для readLine нет перегрузки для 1-го аргумента типа QFile. Ок,  посмотрел тип аргумента, пробую - 
`readData<qint64,QFile,int>(&QFile::readLine,&currentOpenTxt,0)` - та же ошибка, ок, думаю, может хочет возв. знач. как у метода, но
`readData<QByteArray,QFile,int>(&QFile::readLine,&currentOpenTxt,0)` - та же ошибка.

Comment: мне представляется, что readLine является перегруженной функцией и само взятие адреса `&QFile::readLine` без явного указания типа не должно работать

Comment: @user7860670, т.е, если я правильно понял, что-то вроде этого: 
`readData(QFile,&QFile::readLine,&currentOpenTxt,0)` ?

Comment: @user7860670, т.е, я понял о чем Вы (ну, или по крайней мере - мне так кажется), но все равно не могу понять, как правильно осуществить вызов?

Comment: нет, должно быть что-то вроде `readData(static_cast< QByteArray ( QIODevice:: * )(qint64 maxSize) >(&QFile::readLine), p_file, qint64{0});`