# Передать тип возвращаемого значения для шаблонной функции из switch ? ( в вопросе сложночитаемый код)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

**Вступление:**
Есть public метод `OpenFile` со следующей сигнатурой:

```
static bool OpenFile(QString filePath,FileType fTtpe,DataContainerType containerT,QIODevice::OpenModeFlag rwFlag=QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

Помимо всего прочего, в него передается элемент перечисления `DataContainerType`, следующего вида:

```
enum DataContainerType
{
    QStringListContainer,
    QMapContainer,
    ListOfListContaineer
};
```

Внутри `OpenFile` - вызывается шаблонный метод `readData`:

```
template<typename retT,typename containerCastClass,typename castedClassType, typename obj_class, typename obj, typename ...args>
    static retT readData( containerCastClass c,castedClassType c1,obj_class cl, obj o,args... ar);
```

Подробнее, про написание этого метода, я задавал [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157158/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Пример его вызова:

```
   readData<QStringList>(static_cast<QStringList(QVariant::*)() const>(&QVariant::toStringList),
                              static_cast<void(QStringList::*)(const QList<QString> &t)>(&QStringList::append),
                              static_cast< QByteArray ( QIODevice:: * )(qint64 maxSize) >(&QFile::readLine),
                              currentOpenTxt,
                              qint64{0});
```

Собственно, основная работа метода, не учитывая дополнительных проверок:

```
auto read{
        [&]()->auto{
            static auto castedContainer  =  std::invoke(c, currentContainer);// convert QVariant to QStringList, QMap..
            qDebug()<<typeid (castedContainer).raw_name();
            QString readedData=std::invoke(cl,o,ar...); //read line from txt, row/column from xlsx
            std::invoke(c1,castedContainer,retT({readedData}));//append, insert...
            return castedContainer;
        }
    };
```

Суть вопроса:
Как, в зависимости от DataContainerType - задать тип для параметра возвращаемого значения, **не дублируя код?**

Поясню:

Как, вместо этого:

```
switch (containerT) {
    case DataContainerType::QStringListContainer:
        
        readData<QStringList>(static_cast<QStringList(QVariant::*)() const>(&QVariant::toStringList),
                              static_cast<void(QStringList::*)(const QList<QString> &t)>(&QStringList::append),
                              static_cast< QByteArray ( QIODevice:: * )(qint64 maxSize) >(&QFile::readLine),
                              currentOpenTxt,
                              qint64{0});
        
        break;
    case DataContainerType::QMapContainer:
        
        readData<QMap<QString,QString>>(static_cast<QMap<QString,QString>(QVariant::*)() const>(&QVariant::toMap),
                              static_cast<QMap::iterator(QMap<QString,QString>::*)(const Key &key, const T &value)>(&QMap<QString,QString>::insert),
                              static_cast< QByteArray ( QIODevice:: * )(qint64 maxSize) >(&QFile::readLine),
                              currentOpenTxt,
                              qint64{0});
        
        break;
    case DataContainerType::ListOfListContaineer:
        
        readData<QList<QStringList>>(static_cast<QList<QVariant>(QVariant::*)() const>(&QVariant::toList),
                              static_cast<void(QList::*)(const QList<QString> &t)>(&QList<QString>::append),
                              static_cast< QByteArray ( QIODevice:: * )(qint64 maxSize) >(&QFile::readLine),
                              currentOpenTxt,
                              qint64{0});
        
        break;
    }
```

Сделать что-то вроде:
**(псевдокод)**

```
  auto _type;
    auto _toContainer;
    auto containerOperation;
    
    switch (containerT) {
    case DataContainerType::QStringListContainer:
        _type=&QStringList;
        _toContainer=static_cast<QStringList(QVariant::*)() const>(&QVariant::toStringList);
        containerOperation=static_cast<void(QStringList::*)(const QList<QString> &t)>(&QStringList::append);
        break;
    case DataContainerType::QMapContainer:
          _type=&QMap<QString,QString>;
          _toContainer=static_cast<QMap<QString,QString>(QVariant::*)() const>(&QVariant::toMap);
          containerOperation=static_cast<QMap::iterator(QMap<QString,QString>::*)(const Key &key, const T &value)>(&QMap<QString,QString>::insert);
        break;
    case DataContainerType::ListOfListContaineer:
          _type=&QList<QString>
            _toContainer=static_cast<QList<QVariant>(QVariant::*)() const>(&QVariant::toList);
          containerOperation=    static_cast<void(QList::*)(const QList<QString> &t)>(&QList<QString>::append);
        break;
    }
    


readData<_type>(_toContainer,
                                  containerOperation,
                                  static_cast< QByteArray ( QIODevice:: * )(qint64 maxSize) >(&QFile::readLine),
                                  currentOpenTxt,
                                  qint64{0});
```

**Зачем все это нужно!?**

У меня работа метода по сути зависит от двух параметров - тип читаемого файла и тип принимающего контейнера. Так вот, что бы не проверять каждый из 3-х типов контейнеров, для каждого из 3-х (возможно в будущем - больше) типов файлов (понятно, что выполнится одно ветка, но мы говорим про объемы кода и нецелесообразность его дублирования) - хотелось бы вынести эту проверку до проверки типа файла.

Comment: Оффтоп: Раз уж используете Qt то почему бы не применить [qOverload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) вместо `static_cast`?

Comment: @MaximTimakov, к сожадению, я еще не успел особо углубиться в Qt - не знал про это.

Comment: @MaximTimakov при условии что платформа (или требования проекта) поддерживает С++14

Comment: у вас текст сложночитаемый из=за опечаток,лишней пунктуации и стилистики. Надо уметь выражать мысли на любом доступном языке. язык программирования - это язык передачи слоей идеи другим людям , а не только машине. А подойти к этой проблеме надо с другой стороны.. сделать классы- сериализаторы для каждого из типов файлов, выбирать или создавать экземпляр нужного  по типу файла, а методы вызываются уже из класса через виртуальную диспетчеризацию. По крайней мере это будет совпадать с логикой самого Qt

Comment: Можете сделать дополнительный шаблон функции и специализировать его для всех значений из DataContainerType

Answer (score -1):

Я, конечно, не знаю задачи и проекта вообще, но тут я бы реализовал набор классов: базовый (основной функционал и виртуальный метод чтения данных) и Х наследников, в которых виртуальный метод определён.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/511789)

Comment: Является ответом на вопрос. Замечаний автору я не делал. Уточнения мне не нужны. Ответ дан в направлении "вместо дублирования кода используйте ООП". Переписывать его код ради примера - занятие долгое и бесполезное. Судя по всему автор достаточно опытен в плюсах, чтобы понять к чему я клоню.